# Prove that $x^2+y^2=z^4$ has infinitely many solutions with $(x,y,z)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that $x^2+y^2=z^4$ has infinitely many solutions with $(x,y,z)=1$

Since gcd of $(x,y,z)=1$ either $1$ of them is even and the other $2$ are odd or all $3$ are odd.

Since the square of an odd is the form $4k+1$, and the square of an even is $4n$. Then all three cannot be odd because the sum of two squares mod $4$ is $4k+1+4n+1=4(n+k)+2$.

Thus one of $x,y,z$ is even and it cannot be $z$, since then $z^2\equiv 0$ mod $4$ and $x^2+y^2\equiv 2$ mod $4$. So one of $x,y$ is even.

Not sure how to keep going from here.

Comment: Because of $$(n^2-1)^2+2n^2-1=n^4$$ it is enough to show that $2n^2-1$ is a perfect square for infinite many postive integers $n$. This is however well known, since $m^2-2n^2=-1$ has fundamental solution $(1/1)$ and infinite many others can be found by multiplying the matrix $$\pmatrix{3&4\\2&3}$$ with the current solution.

Comment: Note that $n^2-1$ and $n$ are coprime, hence the solution we get with the above approach is always coprime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the standard parameterisation of pythagorean triples , twice !
\begin{eqnarray*}
x=a^2-b^2 \\
y =2ab \\
z^2 = a^2+b^2 
\end{eqnarray*}
And again
\begin{eqnarray*}
a=c^2-d^2 \\
b =2cd \\
z = c^2+d^2 
\end{eqnarray*}
gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
x=c^2-6cd+d^2 \\
y =2cd(c^2-d^2) \\
z = c^2+d^2. 
\end{eqnarray*}